# How to organize a single array into a two-dimensional one?

Tags: java, algorithm, lwjgl

I am trying to split a one dimensional array of display modes into a 2-dimensional string array, though I have encountered trouble where I got to the point of splitting the sorted array of display modes. My question: How can I split the single array, which is already sorted, into a two dimensional array? The code (Sorry about the weird variable names):

```
public static String[][] OrganizeDisplayModes (DisplayMode[] modes) {
    int iter = 0;
    int deltaIter = 0;
    int rows = 0;
    int columns = 0;
    String[][] tobe;
    //bubble sorting
    for (int a = 0; a < modes.length - 1; a++) {
        for(int i = 0; i < modes.length - 1; i++) {
            if (modes[i].getWidth() < modes[i+1].getWidth()) {
                DisplayMode change = modes[i];
                modes[i] = modes[i+1];
                modes[i+1] = change;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < modes.length - 1; i++) {
        if ((modes[i].getWidth() == modes[i+1].getWidth()) && (modes[i].getBitsPerPixel() < modes[i+1].getBitsPerPixel())) {
            DisplayMode change = modes[i];
            modes[i] = modes[i+1];
            modes[i+1] = change;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < modes.length - 1; i++) {
        if ((modes[i].getWidth() == modes[i+1].getWidth()) && (modes[i].getFrequency() < modes[i+1].getFrequency())) {
            DisplayMode change = modes[i];
            modes[i] = modes[i+1];
            modes[i+1] = change;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < modes.length; i++) {
        DisplayMode current = modes[i];
        System.out.println(i + ". " + current.getWidth() + "x" + current.getHeight() + "x" + 
                current.getBitsPerPixel() + " " + current.getFrequency() + "Hz");
    }

    //fit into string array
    for (int i = 0; i < modes.length - 1; i++) {
        if (!(modes[i].getWidth() == modes[i+1].getWidth())) {
            rows += 1;
            deltaIter = i - deltaIter;
            if (deltaIter > columns)
            columns = deltaIter;
        }
    }
    //split the displaymode array into the two-dimensional string one here
    tobe = new String[rows][columns];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int a = 0; a < columns; a++) {
            if((modes[iter].getWidth() == modes[iter+1].getWidth())) {
                tobe[i][a] = iter + ". " + modes[iter].toString() + " ";
            }
            else
                break;
            if (!(iter >= 68))
                iter += 1;
        }
        if (iter >= 68)
            break;
    }
    tobe[rows-1][columns-1] = (iter + 1) + ". " + modes[iter].toString() + " ";
    //test to see that it works
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int a = 0; a < columns; a++) {
            if(tobe[i][a] != null)
                System.out.print(tobe[i][a]);
            else 
                break;
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    System.exit(0);
    return null;
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
0. 1440x900x32 75Hz
1. 1440x900x16 75Hz
2. 1440x900x32 60Hz
3. 1440x900x16 60Hz
```

with all of the different possible resolutions. Basically, what I'm trying to do is make a readable list of the different resolutions, so a user can select their desired one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about storing the information in a different manner? When I made the transition from C to Java I used to use multi-dimensional arrays quite a bit, but it's a pain.

```
public class ScreenType implements Comparable {
    int width;
    int height;
    int color; // not sure what this one was for, assuming 32/16 bit color
    int hertz;

    public ScreenType(int w, int h, int c, int h) {
        width = w;
        height = h;
        color = t;
        hertz = h;
    }

    // remember to maintain transitive property,
    // see JDK documentation for Comparable
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Tuple other) {
    }

    // getters and setters and whatnot

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return width + "X" + height + "X" + color+ "    " + hertz + "hz";
    }
}
```

Then store your screen data like this and use an ArrayList of ScreenTypes which, if I remember right, will sort based on your overriding of compareTo()

Comment: Thank you very much, I am fairly new to java (2 years of self teaching) and you just saved me a major headache.

Comment: Always happy to help. I'm a Junior in Comp Sci myself and know how sometimes arrays can trap you in their simplicity, but Java has such a rich library that I've learned to look there first.

Bookmark the JDK documentation and Oracle Java tutorials. They are great friends of mine.